# QML ListVIew Item Pos

Tags: qt, qml

ListView have 20 items, mouse click to get the tenth item X pos.

But positionViewAtIndex function also move the item.

Is have any way to get Item X pos without positionViewAtIndex?

here is sample.

```
Window {
    id: frame
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            listView.positionViewAtIndex(10, ListView.SnapPosition);
            var destPos = listView.contentX;
            console.log("item10 x: " + destPos)
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 480
        height: 80

        color: "white"

        ListView {
            id:listView
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 20
            clip: true
            model: 20
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            delegate:
                Rectangle {
                width: 40
                height: 40
                color: "green"
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: index
                }
            }
            spacing: 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always try to create a [mcve], removing all irrelevant information for your question. As your question is stated now, it is not clear what you are exactly looking for. Or you looking for `numberDelegate.x`?

Comment: thanks reply, sorry I am late, I try to clear my question.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`x` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop) of the delegate. This is the position relative to the content of the listview.

Comment: Oh yes. I using itemAtIndex() to get the item. thanks a lot. code it the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the way to get the position, but if want center position, it's need more calculate.

```
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        var destPos = listView.itemAtIndex(10).x
        console.log("item10 x: " + destPos)
        listView.contentX = destPos
    }
}
```